# How to get count of NSCountedSet?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get count of values from NSCountedSet using loop and have no idea how to get these.

```
for item in set {

}
```

I'll be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Use method [count(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscountedset/1408658-count)

```
let mySet = NSCountedSet()
mySet.add(1)
mySet.add(2)
mySet.add(2)

for value in mySet {
    let count = mySet.count(for: value)
    print("Count for \(value) is \(count)")
}
```

However, note that `NSCountedSet` is untyped (it's an old Objective-C class), therefore it is not very well suited for Swift.

Luckily, we can implement the same using a simple `[T: Int]` dictionary.

For example:

```
struct MyCountedSet<T: Hashable>: Sequence {
    typealias Element = T
    
    private var counts: [T: Int] = [:]

    mutating func add(_ value: T) {
        counts[value, default: 0] += 1
    }

    func count(for value: T) -> Int {
        return counts[value, default: 0]
    }

    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<T> {
        return AnyIterator<T>(counts.keys.makeIterator())
    }
}

var myCountedSet = MyCountedSet<Int>()
myCountedSet.add(1)
myCountedSet.add(2)
myCountedSet.add(2)

for value in myCountedSet {
    let count = myCountedSet.count(for: value)
    print("Count for \(value) is \(count)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would call [`count(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscountedset/1408658-count) on the set:

```
import Foundation

let set: NSCountedSet = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"]

for item in set {
    print("\(set.count(for: item)) x \"\(item)\"")
}
```

Prints:

```
1 x "a"
2 x "b"
3 x "c"
```